# Printing Contents of ExpandoObject to an Indented String

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am currently working on a program that takes JSON input and deserializes it using JSON.NET into a dynamic ExpandoObject. Then through a function, I want to dump it out into another textbox to show what it could possibly represent as C# objects. How would I indent my string to show my hierarchical ExpandoObject and take it from a flat list of data to a tree structure of data I can send to a textbox as a string?

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
if (tbxJSON.Text != "")
{
        // Create an ExpandoObjectConverter in order to hold the dynamic parsed JSON.
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic convertedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(tbxJSON.Text, converter);

            tbxCSharp.Text = "";

        // Loop through the ExpandoObject and print out all of the values in the dynamic object using a recursive function.
        foreach (var property in (IDictionary<string, object>)convertedJSON)
                sb.Append(ExpandoToString(property.Value, property.Key));

        // Set C# output to contents of StringBuilder.
        tbxCSharp.Text = sb.ToString();
}

private string ExpandoToString(object propVal, string propName)
{
    string retStr = "";

    // If we are dealing with nested JSON
    if (propVal.GetType() == typeof(ExpandoObject))
    {
        // Append this object type.
        sb.Append(Indent(indentIdx) + UppercaseFirst(propName) + " " + propName + " consists of..." + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (var prop in (IDictionary<string, object>)propVal)
        {
            if (prop.Value.GetType() == typeof(ExpandoObject))
                sb.Append(ExpandoToString(prop.Value, prop.Key));
            else
            {
                if (prop.Value.GetType() == typeof(List<dynamic>))
                {
                    // TO DO
                }
                else
                    sb.Append(ExpandoToString(prop.Value, prop.Key));
            }
        }
    }
    else 
            retStr = propVal.GetType() + " : " + propName + " = " + propVal + Environment.NewLine;

    return retStr;
}


Test JSON:
{"airline":"Oceanic","number":815,"departure":{"IATA":"SYD","time":"2004-09-22 14:55","city":"Sydney"},"arrival":{"IATA":"LAX","time":"2004-09-23 10:42","city":"Los Angeles"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should supply your current indent as a parameter to the `ExpandoToString()` method and increment it any time it calls itself.

```
private string ExpandoToString(object propVal, string propName, int indent = 0)
{

    ...

    // Append this object type.
    sb.Append(Indent(indent) + UppercaseFirst(propName) + " " + propName + " consists of..." + Environment.NewLine);

    ...

    sb.Append(ExpandoToString(propVal, propName, indent + 1) ...);
```